# Bang! Is a Bang needed to shoot back with Backfire?

Tags: bang

The Backfire card says "The player who shot is the target of a BANG!"
Does that mean that the player who shot is automatically a target of a Bang, or does the player playing Backfire need to use a Bang with it to actually backfire on the other player?

Answer (score 3):

From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bang!_(card_game)) page for bang

> BackFire – Counts as Missed!. Any player who targeted you with Bang! is now a target of Bang!.

The card says it correctly that the payer who shot you is the target of a bang. If you needed to play a bang also for it to work that would be listed on the card as well.